# d3.js: styling <text> does not work

Tags: d3.js, svg

So I have a chart created with d3.js. When I hover dots on the chart, I want to show text with border and background-color.

Right now, only text with no style will appear on hover and my code (tooltip) looks like this:

```
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.width/2 + cfg.margin.left) + "," + (cfg.height/2 + cfg.margin.top) + ")");

on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
    var newX =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
    var newY =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 10;

    tooltip
       .attr('x', newX)
       .attr('y', newY)
       .text(Format(d.value))
       .transition().duration(200)
       .style('opacity', 1)    
})
.on("mouseout", function(){
    tooltip.transition().duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0);
});

var tooltip = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

When I add style to `.tooltip`, it does not change anything. Then when I change `g.append("text")` to anything else such as `g.append("foreignObject")`, `g.append("div")`, etc, they do not even appear on hover (they are showing in console elements).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What style are you going to add to class `tooltip`? You are missing out the most vital part of your question—the styling itself!

Comment: @altocumulus I believe OP is trying to apply `background-color` and `border`. But I agree with you, it's not very clear.

Comment: @altocumulus sorry for not being clear, but the answer from Gerardo Furtado is what I wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to apply some HTML styles to an SVG `<text>` or `<g>` element, and that will not work.

If you want to style the border, border radius, background color etc, you should use a `<div>` to show your tooltip, so you can apply any style you want, since the div is an HTML element. However, there is a catch: you cannot append a div or any other HTML element to an SVG.

Thus, a solution is appending your tooltip div to the `<body>`, and setting its position with `d3.event.pageY` and `d3.event.pageX`.

Check this demo, with a simplified version of the tooltip. You can set all the styles in the CSS, but I'm setting the styles in the D3 code just for you to see how it works. None of these styles would work with a SVG text element:

```js
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var circle = d3.select("circle")
    .on("mousemove", function() {
        tooltip.html("Hello")
            .style("background-color", "tan")
            .style("border", "1px solid black")
            .style("padding", "2px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY + 10 + "px")
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px")
            .style("opacity", 1);
    }).on("mouseout", function() {
        tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

```css
.tooltip {
 position: absolute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```